# Sed - html replacement

Tags: html, sed

Here is the input I have and the output I want:

**Input:**

```
<hr /> 
(newline)
( carriage return)
    (tabs, spaces)<div id="sidebar">
```

**Output:**

```
</div>
<hr />
(newline)
( carriage return)
    (tabs, spaces)<div id="sidebar">
```

This doesn't seem to match it:

```
sed -i 's/<hr \/>[[:space:]]*<div id="sidebar">/<\/div><hr \/><div id="sidebar">/g' file.txt
```

Hrm?

Comment: I just didn't know how to actually have html code snippets; it was displaying my elements prior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can really do this with `sed`, because I don't know of any way to convince it to operate on multiple lines at once.  It really wants to operate on one line at a time.  You can do it reasonably easily with Perl, though:

```
perl -pi -e 's/<hr \/>\s*<div id="sidebar">/<\/div><hr \/><div id="sidebar">/gs;' -e 'BEGIN { $/ = ""; }' file.txt
```

Comment: Using N, you can make sed work on multiple lines, but perl is definitely the right way to go here.

Comment: interesting. what would be a strategy for using this operation on multiple files?

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ( your command ) {} \;  
?

Answer (score 0):

then you don't really need to do substitution. just check for the `"<hr >"` line, then print `"</div>"` before it.

```
awk '/<hr \/>/{    print "</div>" } 1 ' file
```